# Custom theming of login form

Tags: 7

I have used drupal built in form `user_login` and `user_register_form`, Is there a way to control label and textbox field separately, because in my markup each label and text field have different wrapping divs. For example, I have render a particular field like below:

```
<?php print render($form['name']); ?>
```

If I apply a wrapping div around this then it is applicable on both label and text field but I have separate divs with different class for each label and field. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is override the field template [field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7).

To target specific fields you can rename your version of the file as per the [template suggestion options for the field template](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656#field-suggestion).